# Facebook meta tags, meta tags in body errors

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

Having problem with facebook meta tags. Have seen questions asked like this and have checked and rechecked the meta tags but cant see the problem, am a newbie to writing code so that might be the problem i.e. putting code in the wrong places, website is www.candcautos.ie, would appreciate if anyone could have a look to see what the problem is, e.g tags outside of head etc. Have like button working but its not showing up on "likees" newsfeed when they click the like button. The error below is whats showing up when i use the facebook debug/linter, along with meta tag warnings and inferred property warnings but I presume if I fix that first the others should fix themselves. Would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks

"You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have embedded one entire HTML document into another – which of course is not allowed. An HTML document can contain the Elements `html`, `body`, `head` only once.

Go fix your HTML errors – the validator lists them up for you, http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.candcautos.ie/home/

Answer (score 1):

Do you use AddThis? That add on will do exactly what has been described by the last poster.
You can only run one like/send service.

If you want to use Facebook buttons directly you need to look at stop using AddThis or similar service.

Comment: This is not really an answer, more of a guess. Please use comments for such.